# What's the syntax for nested conditional statements?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I want to check if $AD = 1, then if not pass to another function, but if $AD = 1 check if AC = contains some value, if not do some stuff.

```
if ($AD == '1'){
if ($AC == ''){
echo 'AC is empty';
} else { 
///////Function/////
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should help him instead of giving him a down vote !

Comment: Try to walk before you run. Have a read through this awesome documentation -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `else if` statement must always correspond to a beginning `if` statement on the same "nesting level".

Your inner `else if` does not have any beginning `if` statement and it therefore fails.

```
if ($AD == 1) {
  if ($AC == '') {
    echo 'empty';
  }
}
else {
  otherFunction($AD);
}
```

Since this is basic PHP (actually IFs are mostly not language-dependent) stuff,  I recommend you reading a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: You must realise that otherFunction($AD) won't execute on either true or false of $AC since otherFunction($AD) is outside the scope of $AC, so otherFunction($AD) must be on the branches of AD, not on a different tree altogether, in this case, otherFunction($AD) executes on the conditions of $AD, whereas AD depends on AC and otherFunction($AD) doesn't depend on AC, making otherFunction($AD) not to execute at all. Please review your answer.

Comment: @Eustatia I'm sorry, but I do not fully understand your text. If you know how to program your logic, then please post an answer yourself or clarify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($AD == 1){
  if ($AC == ''){
    // some code where ac has the value
   } else {
     // some code where ac doesn't have the value
   }
 } else  {
   // other function
 }
```

That should do it

Comment: Do you realise that you have two nested functions that one depends on the other? 'Other function' should be inside the body of condition $AC.

Comment: @Eustatia You said "I want to check if $AD = 1, then if not pass to another function" Hense my code of: if ( $AD == 1 ) { blah } else { other function}.